# Can i add a document or information into envelope after creating (second sign) DOCUSIGN

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

i use docusign for electronic signature.
I ask if i can add a document after creating the envelopeId in the second signing

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional documents to the envelope as long as you have not sent the envelope yet.  Once you send it (and the envelope has changed to `sent` status) you will not be able to add more documents.  Put another way, you can only add documents to *draft* envelopes.

To add document(s) to a draft envelope use the [EnvelopeDocuments: update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/update) API

Ex:

```
PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}
```